# Drupal7: How could Contextual filter: Content: Nid return the TNID instead of NID in Views3

Tags: internationalization, drupal-7, drupal-views, contextual-binding

I have a ***Contextual filter: Content: Nid*** in Views3 that I want to return the TNID instead of the NID *When the filter value is NOT available*.

I tried

```
$node=node_load($argument);
$argument = $node->tnid;
return $argument;
```

or

```
$node=node_load(arg(1));
$argument = $node->tnid; // bzw. $argument(1) = $node->tnid;
return $argument;
```

and others from inside the *Provide default value:PHP Code* Field. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by adding this code to the page.tpl.php

```
$imagemenuview = views_get_view('projectimagemenu');
echo $imagemenuview->preview('block', array($node->tnid));
```

but still interested in the solution using *Contextual filter: Content: Nid* returning the TNID instead of the NID *When the filter value is NOT available*